# Mac OS X connections on port 80,443 not resolving

Tags: macos, networking

I am using a macbook pro, and connections on port 80 and 443 aren't resolving. To write this, i am ssh tunnelling through another computer in my house. The proxy settings in System Preferences are normal. What i did do is recently remove a network filtering program that was starting in /Library/LaunchDaemons, even though i had uninstalled it (it was returning a NSPOSIX error)

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: What filtering program, and are you sure you *fully* removed it?

Comment: I removed everything in the LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents folder, as well as the program files.

Comment: What was the program? Does it do anything other than install Launch*'s and program files (e.g. make persistent settings changes to one of OS X's built-in firewalls)? If you want help with this, you really need to give us enough information to work with.

Comment: Don't worry, i fixed it. I upgraded to the latest version of Mac, and the problem vanished....